# Difference between RSSI and Received Power

Tags: power, radio

Is Received Power and RSSI same thing? I have been looking into it and think they are the same. But please guide me the difference between them if they are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not, RSSI only gives an indication of the received power. If you would have a large interfering signal on the same channel or an adjacent channel your RSSI value would be high yet the Received Power of the wanted signal would be low.

For proper receiver power measurements you will need a power meter or a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: I'd like to know where do you get that RSSI stands for Relative...: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication

Comment: OK, my bad, changing my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Now be careful, signal strength will not tell you the whole story, you have to look at the LQI (Link Quality Indicator) also. You can have a high RSSI but also have high noise in your signal.

Comment: Is LQI similar to SNR  ?

Comment: Sort of, but not exactly. It is a measure of the signal strength vs the number of errors received.